# JAXB/XJC - XML Schema Parsin Fail

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am currently working with JAXB (and its tool XJC) to "translate" an XML Schema (.xsd) to auto-generated java classes.

I execute the following command :

```
java -jar "../lib/com.sun.jaxb_1.0.0/jaxb-xjc.jar" schema.xsd
```

But, obviously, I don't get to compile my schema and get the following errors :

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 : Le contenu de 'heureType' n'est pas valide. L'élément 'element' n'est pas valide, est mal placé ou compte trop d'occurrences.
line 9 of file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/schema.xsd

[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 : Le contenu de 'demandeCri' n'est pas valide. L'élément 'element' n'est pas valide, est mal placé ou compte trop d'occurrences.
line 24 of file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/schema.xsd

[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 : Le contenu de 'infoCri' n'est pas valide. L'élément 'element' n'est pas valide, est mal placé ou compte trop d'occurrences.
line 28 of file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/schema.xsd

[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 : Le contenu de 'criType' n'est pas valide. L'élément 'element' n'est pas valide, est mal placé ou compte trop d'occurrences.
line 33 of file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/schema.xsd

[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 : Le contenu de 'initLiaison' n'est pas valide. L'élément 'element' n'est pas valide, est mal placé ou compte trop d'occurrences.
line 46 of file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/schema.xsd

[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 : Le contenu de 'listeCri' n'est pas valide. L'élément 'element' n'est pas valide, est mal placé ou compte trop d'occurrences.
line 50 of file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/schema.xsd

[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 : Le contenu de 'fichierCri' n'est pas valide. L'élément 'element' n'est pas valide, est mal placé ou compte trop d'occurrences.
line 67 of file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/schema.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

sorry for the french, but the error can be translated as something like this :

```
[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1 : The content of 'heureType' is not valid. The element 'element' is not valid, is misplaced or appears to many times.
```

I tried to change the order of my code in multiple ways, but got nothing good.

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 

<!-- the Root Element -->
<xs:element name="fichier_cri" type="fichierCri"/> 


<!-- ########## LEVEL 0 ########## -->

    <xs:complexType name="fichierCri"> 
    <xs:element name="init_liaison" type="initLiaison" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="liste_cri" type="listeCri" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType> 


<!-- ########## LEVEL 1 ########## -->  

<xs:complexType name="initLiaison"> 
    <xs:element name="source" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="listeCri"> 
    <xs:element name="demande_cri" type="demandeCri" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="info_cri" type="infoCri" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="cri" type="criType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<!-- ########## LEVEL 2 ########## -->  

<xs:complexType name="demandeCri"> 
        <xs:element name="fichier_erreur" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="infoCri"> 
        <xs:element name="nb_erreur" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
        <xs:element name="num_proch_erreur" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="criType"> 
        <xs:element name="num_erreur" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
        <xs:element name="num_cri" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
        <xs:element name="heure" type="heureType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
        <xs:element name="data" type="dataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
</xs:complexType> 


<!-- ########## LEVEL 3 ########## -->  

<xs:complexType name="heureType"> 
        <xs:element name="secondes" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
        <xs:element name="nano_secondes" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="dataType"> 
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="octet" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType> 


<!-- *** end *** -->    
</xs:schema> *
```

does someone know something about this ? :/

Comment: Does this bit look suspect - there is no opening <complexType> <!-- ########## LEVEL 1 ########## -->  

    <xs:element name="source" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
</xs:complexType>

Comment: Maybe it is the order try to declare the components before the composed :  begin level 3 to level 0

Comment: @DaveH oops sorry, a little paste error ^^' it's corrected ;)

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque I tried it already, but it did nothing... :/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_example.asp you miss <xs:sequence> nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that your xsd file is not syntactically correct. This is true. If you edit your xsd to fix the problems, the error messages should go away.

When you define a complex type:

```
<complexType name="foo">
    <sequence>
        <element ... />
        <element ... />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Make sure that all elements within your complex types are within a sequence element. The `<sequence>` says that a valid document will contain the contained elements in the specified order.

Of course, there are other options available for defining your complex type. For example, you can use `<choice>` instead of `<sequence>`, which means that a valid document will contain one of the contained elements.

It is worthwhile to look at the schema (xsd) for schema files. Check out the link that you have in the top of your schema file (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema).

Comment: Okay thanks, it worked. I didn't know the complexType must contain a sequence... but then what does the "sequence" means ? I thought it was to describe elements that could occurs multiple times, like elements of a List or something.

Comment: @KingKunu I edited the answer to add a bit more detail about the various options for complex types and a pointer to the source of all answers (the schema for schemas).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I get it now ! It was absolutely not what I thought it was ! ^^'