# Malformed XML while unmarshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

**EDIT :** thanks to Preetam Kumar, this problem is solved, but the error is elsewhere now. When I try to unmarshall my xml file again, I get this error telling me the element cannot be found :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/xml/exemple1.xml; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 185; cvc-elt.1 : Declaration of element 'crifile' cannot be found.]
```

However, I give the xml file the correct path to the schema but it seems it does not use it... I don't understand.

NB : I know the schema and xml tags doesn't match completely in the examples bellow, I already corrected it in my files.

---

These days I have to work with the JAXB java library to parse some XML files into Java Objects.

I made an XML Schema (.xsd) and used the tool xjc to compile it and generate my Java Classes. (see my question here for an example of the xsd file : [schema.xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528099/jaxb-xjc-xml-schema-parsin-fail/38529722) )

Now, I am trying to test my schema and the generated classes by unmarshalling a custom XML file. And here is my problem. 
I constantly get an error that my xml is malformed right from the start, when I declare the namespace, as I have seen in numerous websites and examples :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/> 
<xsi:schemaLocation="***\Workspace_XML\fichier_cri\schema.xsd"/>
```

I get the error :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/xml/exemple1.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 11; The type of element "xmlns:xsi" must be followed by attribut specifications, ">" or "/>".]
```

I tried modifying the line and even removed it, but then I get another error :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:***/Workspace_XML/fichier_cri/xml/exemple1.xml; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 10; cvc-elt.1 : Déclaration of element 'crifile' not found.]
```

right now, I don't know what to do anymore, so if someone have a hint or something, I won't say no...

I am not really confident in my Java test program either... but here it is :

```
import generated.FichierCri;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class main {

    final static File   baseDir = new File("***\\Workspace_XML\\fichier_cri\\");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - load xml stream");
        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - xml file location : " + baseDir.getPath() + "\\xml\\exemple1.xml");

        File xmlFile = new File(baseDir, "\\xml\\exemple1.xml");

        if (xmlFile == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("xmlFile is null");

        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - Instantiate SchemaFactory");

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - Load schema file");
        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - schema location : " + baseDir.getPath() + "\\schema\\schema.xsd");

        Schema schema = null;
        try {
            schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(baseDir, "\\schema\\schema.xsd"));
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (schema == null) throw new NullPointerException("schema is null");

        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - Instantiate JAXBContext");

        JAXBContext context = null;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FichierCri.class);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - create unmarshaller");

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
        try {
            unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - set schema to unmarshaller");

        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - Create unmarshall object of type FichierCri");
        System.out.println("*DEBUG* - unmarshall from xml file");

        try {
            FichierCri unmarshall = (FichierCri) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a sample of the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/> 
<xsi:schemaLocation="***\Desktop\Workspace_XML\fichier_cri\schema.xsd"/>

<crifile>
    <init_liaison>
        <source>value</source>
    </init_liaison>
    <liste_cri>
        <demande_cri>
            <fichier_erreur>value</fichier_erreur>
        </demande_cri>
    </liste_cri>
</crifile>
```

all the elements (crifile, liste_cri,...) are defined in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML you have is really malformed as you can test online [here for validation](https://validator.w3.org/check). What your XML provides is multiple root nodes/elements in the XML body as there should be only one XML body and the **xmlns:xsi** and **xsi:schemaLocation** should belong to the only root element which in your case is the **crifile** element.

Your XML should look like shown below after correction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<crifile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="PATH_TO_SCHEMA_FILE\schema.xsd">
    <init_liaison>
        <source>value</source>
    </init_liaison>
    <liste_cri>
        <demande_cri>
            <fichier_erreur>value</fichier_erreur>
        </demande_cri>
    </liste_cri>
</crifile>
```

Where PATH_TO_SCHEMA_FILE should be replaced with the proper location of your schema file.

Comment: Okay thanks, it effectively solved my problem, but then, i have another problem... I edited the question with the new error.

Comment: what do you mean by "you should provide the xml format" ?

Comment: let me have a look.

Comment: by the way I didn't mean to include that text. I have removed it now. :)

Comment: I think there is a problem in your schema.xsd file. Are you sure the crifile is defined properly in your schema.xsd file?

Comment: based on the examples I got to see, I think so. Since crifile is my root element, i delcared it like this : `<xs:element name="cri_file" type="criFile"/>` and then, the criFile type is described like this : `<xs:complexType name="fichierCri"> 
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="init_liaison" type="initLiaison" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> 
   
   <xs:element name="liste_cri" type="listeCri" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType> ` wich is I assume, the same pattern found in the xml file.

Comment: maybe it would have to do with the java this time ? like I should use the objectFactory generated from xjc or something ? But I don't really get how it works yet :/

Answer (score 1):

Your xml is malformed, your header should look something like this (xmlns and schemaLocation are attributes of the root node and not separated elements):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <root_element xmlns="uri to ns" 
              xmlns:xsi="uri_to schema instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="uri to schema location">
...
    </root_element>
```

Check these links for more info:

[general xml tutorial in french - based on the "fichier_erreur" I guess this is your prefered language](http://xmlfr.org/documentations/faq/041217-0001)

[how to reference local files for schemaLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253402/how-to-reference-a-local-xml-schema-file-correctly)